# Is wire-wrap for components, or just special boards and pins?

Tags: connector, components, wiring, protoboard

Are common components suitable for wire-wrap connections?  Or is wire wrap designed for a special type of pin?

I just checked some resistors and diodes and found them ranging from .5-.7mm, and the legs on a MOSFET are rectangular, ranging from .65-1.65mm.

I was looking at one hand-wrap tool for 22-24AWG wrap wire and it specifies a "wrap post size" of 1.14mm.  How precise must the size of the wrapped conductor be to the tool's specification?

Also, is it important that wrap wire be plated in tin or silver?

Comment: The wire wrap post should be square or rectangular, so that the sharp corners can bite into the wire.  Round component leads won't work so well, as there are no sharp corners to prevent the wrapped wire from loosening.

Comment: Although there's nothing wrong with wrapping a component lead and then immediately soldering it. The wrapping keeps the wire from trying to get away while you solder it.

Comment: There are [wire-wrap sockets](http://www.jameco.com/1/3/dip-wire-wrap-ic-sockets) available to let you connect to parts with round pins.

Comment: What you really need are DIP component adapters http://www.jameco.com/1/1/11412-616-cg1-connector-dip-adapter-pl-pl-16-position-2-54mm-solder-straight-thru-hole.html You solder the components to the adapter and plug the adapter into a DIP socket (like wire-wrap). Such adapters are also available in 8, 14 and 20 pin models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I talked to a tech at [Jonard](http://jonard.com/Categories/SecondaryCategory.aspx?reset=y&g=%7B7D90C9F4-531B-4214-80F6-D6D6A735668F%7D), which has made a lot of these tools.  He clarified the following:

1. Wrap wire does not need to be plated.
2. The diameter of the wrap tool or bit can't be very much larger than the diagonal of the wrapping post or else the wrap will not be tight.
3. Wire wrap was not designed for it, but if you can match the wrapping bit to it you can wrap a round conductor and it will make a good electrical connection.  But you would then have to solder or mechanically secure the wrap from sliding off the end.